# Are comments indexed by Google?

Tags: support, comments, google, search-engine

Are comments made on SE sites indexed by Google? Or is the site configured in such a way that only questions and answered are "seen" by Google robots?

I know [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37030/312691) appears related, but its text doesn't mention comments even though its title does – and none of the responses address comments.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Some of them.

You can prove this by finding any random comment that has been around for awhile and searching for it in Google.  It will appear in the search results.

Google will (naturally) prioritize posts to comments, but it will search comments if there is a far closer match than there is in posts.

Screenshot of Google search for [this random comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37030/can-google-search-engines-see-deleted-posts-or-comments#comment80425_37030):

[image: Googling for comments]

---

Crazy Ivan has a good point, though: if the comments are hidden by a "Show more comments" link, they will not be indexed by Google; they would only be shown when a JavaScript link is followed, and consequently, Google does not find them.  For instance, searching for

> Point 3 under "Scraping users’ profile", "Nothing about this transfers any rights from our users to us" seems to include the implicit understanding that SE already has the legal ability to allow access to that information.

does not come up with [this random comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/a-terms-of-service-update-restricting-companies-that-scrape-your-profile-informa#comment898589_277369):

[image: No results found]

Comment: It's worth considering that when a post has many comments, only a few of them appear in the markup of the page, the rest are loaded only if the link to show all comments is clicked. It's not clear to me whether the second category is indexed (I.e. whether Google bot executes the JavaScript behind that link).